# Error while Lauching Snap Store

Tags: software-installation

While I tried to run the Snap store on my newly installed 20.04 LTS version from terminal without sudo, I get these errors-

```
~$ snap-store
05:52:04:0142 Gs  enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata05:52:04:0142 Gs  disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions
05:52:04:0375 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
05:52:04:0377 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
05:52:04:0378 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
05:52:04:0378 Gs  failed to get system app
05:52:04:0378 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
05:52:05:0184 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
05:52:05:0184 Gs  hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
05:52:05:0253 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
05:52:05:0818 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
05:52:06:0419 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
```

If I use Sudo then I get these errors

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
05:58:51:0429 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
05:58:51:0432 Gtk cannot open display: :0
```

How Can I solve these issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Software app in Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install gnome-software`
2. Search for Snap Store in the Software app, click on Snap Store to go to the Snap Store screen, and click the  <kbd>Launch</kbd>  button to launch it from the Software app.
3. After the Snap Store is open it will prompt you in the GUI to get the required updates. You will also get a popup authentication window if you need to authenticate with your password in order to update the Snap Store.
4. Check if the Snap Store works by searching for an app that has a snap package like gedit or emacs.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But it also worked when I ran it from the Terminal. But I'd get those errors in terminal. No other issues.